# Play! Binding UI values to a model

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play 1.2.5

I have a `User` model as below:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
public String name;
public String city;
public String country;
public Integer zip;
}
```

The `registration.html` file is like this:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

<form action="@{Application.registerUser()}" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="txtName"><br>
City: <input type="text" name="txtCity"><br>
Country: <input type="text" name="txtCountry"><br>
Zip: <input type="text" name="txtZip"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Below is the `registerUser` method in Application Controller:

```
public static void registerUser(String txtName,String txtCity,String txtCountry,Integer txtZip){
    //some business logic
    render();
}
```

The above signature works fine but I have to add a lot of parameters in the method which I dont want.

In a form, I have more than 15 fields, in such a case 15 parameters are too much!!!

Hence I need to know how to bind the user input values to a model (e.g. user model shown above) and pass it to the controller as an `user` object parameter to the method or as a map with key and value pairs (which ever is easier)?

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your input fields to `user.name`, `user.city`, etc., and change the controller method to

```
public static void registerUser(User user)
```

This is described in [the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#pojo).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Somewhere I saw a syntax something like: `#{form...} #{/form}`. Can the same achieved using that syntax? Not sure what is it for can you please let me know what is it for?

Comment: Yes, the same can be achieved. The form tag is also described in the documentation: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/tags#form